# Is this implementation of padding useless?

Tags: hash, cryptography, padding

I am relatively new to cryptography, so I'd like to ask a very basic question.

Say I take the string "Hello World" and I pad it out with "1 0 0 0 ...." until the block is a predefined size. Then I hash that.

If I use this hashed value in an encryption system, isn't the padding kind of useless, since someone can just assemble that include "Hello World10000..." based on just looking at the size of the signature (to deduce the encryption type) and then based on typical padding algorithms construct tables that incorporate the padding?

I believe I suffer from some basic misunderstandings!

Perhaps (?) the only way to make the above system useful is to always pad with a random pad--yet "ISO 10126" was discontinued according to wiki, and that system used random padding. How should I rectify this confusion?

Comment: Are you talking about [*salting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))?

Comment: Well, like I said, I seem to have a misunderstanding. I'm refferring to this article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography) where it talks about "My dear ambassador..."

Comment: I don't really follow what you are trying to achieve, but padding is not trivial to implement in a cryptographically secure way. What exactly is the goal of your scheme?

Comment: To understand whether this basic case of padding is useless or not, purely for learning experience. And to correct any misunderstanding which I clearly have about the basics.

Comment: The padding of "my dear ambassador" described in the wikipedia article is for encryption, not hashing. The article talks about padding to remove predictable plain text, padding for hashes (and also for many encryption algorithms) is to obtain an input where its length is a multiple of a block size.

Comment: So when you're talking about padding out a hash, the padding isn't a security measure, just a logistical operation?

Comment: Exactly. However, the padding has to be done in a secure way. (See the length extension attack described in the wikipedia article.)

Comment: There is no way with a MD based hash to avoid length extension attacks with just padding. This is because the last chaining value is equal to the output. You need something to delimit the operations, instead of just something to delimit the input data.

Comment: There are too many issues with the question for it to be answerable in my opinion. I'm not even sure which padding you're referring to. I'd guess the padding of the hash function? What kind of tables / attack are you referring to? Why does it matter if an attacker can construct tables containing possible plaintext and padding?

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons basically to perform padding:

1. length-extension: padding is used to make the input adhere to size restrictions of the following functions;
2. security: padding is performed so the resulting value enhances the security for the following functions.

---

The first reason is used for ECB and CBC modes of operation and most forms of cryptographic hashes. Both use a specific block size internally and the input size needs to be an exact number of times the block size.

Now for cryptographic hashes the padding is considered an integral part of the algorithm. So internally it pads the message with a single bit set to 1 and then an x number of zeros, where x is between 0 and the block size. This is usually called bit padding. As *bit padding* is always applied, the padded message remains unique, which is of course required for cryptographic hashes.

You can obviously not perform random padding for the input of hash functions. It would result in random output.

---

The second padding reason is used e.g. during RSA signature generation and encryption. This is used to pad the hash output itself. After the padding the RSA modular exponentiation is performed. The padding is required as raw RSA is vulnerable against all sorts of attacks (if your message consists of a number with value 1, then exponentiation would result in the number 1, to name just a single issue).

For RSA encryption randomness inside the padding is required. RSA padding is however quite different from bit padding; ISO 10126 certainly doesn't apply.